# Excel Looping through rows and copy cell values to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am facing some difficulty in achieving the desired result for my `macro`.

**Intention**:

I have a list of data in `sheets(input).column A` (the number of rows that has value will vary and hence I created a loop that will run the macro until the activecell is blank).

My macro starts from `Range(A2)` and stretches all the way down column A, it stops only when it hits a blank row

Desired result for the macro will be to start copying the cell value in `sheet(input).Range(A2)` paste it to `sheet(mywork).Range(B2:B6)`.

For example, if "Peter" was the value in cell `sheet(input),range(A2)` then when the marco runs and paste the value into `sheet(mywork) range(B2:B6)`. ie range `B2:B6` will reflect "Peter"

Then the macros loop back to sheet(input) & copy the next cell value and paste it to `range(B7:B10)`

**Example**: "Dave" was the value in `sheet(input) Range(A3)`, then "Dave" will be paste into the next 4 rows in `sheet(mywork).Range(B7:B10)`. `B7:B10` will reflect "Dave"

Again repeating the same process goes back to sheet(input) this time `range(A4)`, copys the value goes to sheet(mywork) and paste it into `B11:B15`.

Basically the process repeats....

The macro ends the when the activecell in `sheet(input) column A` is empty.

```
Sub playmacro()
    Dim xxx As Long, yyy As Long
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("A2").Activate
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        DoEvents
        ActiveCell.Copy
        For xxx = 2 To 350 Step 4
            yyy = xxx + 3
            Worksheets("mywork").Activate 
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range(Cells(xxx, 2), Cells(yyy, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
        Next xxx
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

Dim Z As Long 
Dim Cellidx As Range 
Dim NextRow As Long 
Dim Rng As Range 
Dim SrcWks As Worksheet 
Dim DataWks As Worksheet 
Z = 1 
Set SrcWks = Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Set DataWks = Worksheets("Sheet2") 
Set Rng = EntryWks.Range("B6:ad6") 

NextRow = DataWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
NextRow = IIf(NextRow = 1, 1, NextRow + 1) 

For Each RA In Rng.Areas 
    For Each Cellidx In RA 
        Z = Z + 1 
        DataWks.Cells(NextRow, Z) = Cellidx 
    Next Cellidx 
Next RA 
End Sub
```

Alternatively

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("P2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L10")
```

This is a CopynPaste - Method

```
Sub CopyDataToPlan()

Dim LDate As String
Dim LColumn As Integer
Dim LFound As Boolean

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Retrieve date value to search for
LDate = Sheets("Rolling Plan").Range("B4").Value

Sheets("Plan").Select

'Start at column B
LColumn = 2
LFound = False

While LFound = False

  'Encountered blank cell in row 2, terminate search
  If Len(Cells(2, LColumn)) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "No matching date was found."
     Exit Sub

  'Found match in row 2
  ElseIf Cells(2, LColumn) = LDate Then

     'Select values to copy from "Rolling Plan" sheet
     Sheets("Rolling Plan").Select
     Range("B5:H6").Select
     Selection.Copy

     'Paste onto "Plan" sheet
     Sheets("Plan").Select
     Cells(3, LColumn).Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
     False, Transpose:=False

     LFound = True
     MsgBox "The data has been successfully copied."

     'Continue searching
      Else
         LColumn = LColumn + 1
      End If

   Wend

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
  MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

And there might be some methods doing that in Excel.