# Excel VBA: Check if cell in another workbook contains String before performing task

Tags: vba, excel, macros

NOTE:  This question works off of my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051989/excel-vba-how-to-loop-through-workbooks-in-same-folder-using-given-code/40052340?noredirect=1#comment67497628_40052340).

Here is a background of my problem.  I have multiple test files of the same format in a folder.  I need to count the specific amount of "YES" in a column in each work book.  From my previous question, I was able to obtain a macro that traverses through each file, count the "YES", and put the counter in a Master Workbook.  The following macro shows this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim r As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = getYesCount(r.Value)
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function getYesCount(WorkBookName As String) As Long
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\khanr1\Desktop\CodeUpdateTest\"

    If Len(Dir(FolderPath & WorkBookName)) Then
        With Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & WorkBookName)
            With .Worksheets("Sheet2")
                getYesCount = Application.CountIf(.Range("D:D"), "YES")
            End With
            .Close False
        End With
    Else
        Debug.Print FolderPath & WorkBookName; ": Not Found"
    End If
End Function
```

**Now the issue I have is to add a feature that counts the "YES" ONLY if there is a String "Warning" adjacent to it.  Please refer to the following snapshot of one of the test files:**

[image: Warning Snap]

Here is a snapshot of the Master Workbook (CountResults.xlsm):

[image]

My idea was to create an 'If' function that checks to see if the cell contains "Warning" and if so, proceed to count the YES column. And as a side note, I cannot make a macro that just sees if the column has a string, because the column may have multiple strings.  It needs to specify the "Warning" or "Warning*" (in case there are details following it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  getYesCount = Application.CountIfs(.Range("D:D"), "YES", _
                                     .Range("B:B"), "Warning*")
```